# Bitbucket pipeline - deploy to Azure app service using ncftpput fails mid way

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket-pipelines

We established continuous integration from bitbucket to azure app service deployment using pipelines. It was working fine all this time, from early this week it is failing mid way of copying process.

we are using ncftpput to ftp the files from bitbucket to azure, sample one given below.

```
ncftpput -v -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" -R $FTP_HOST /site/wwwroot/Views *
```

It starts copying the files but after copying some of the files, we get this error....

```
Passive mode refused.
ncftpput pdf.png: passive mode failed.
```

with -d stdout in ncftput, sample log output...

```
Cmd: PASV
227: Entering Passive Mode (40,120,124,239,39,110).
Cmd: STOR SuperAccount/CreateAdminUser.cshtml
150: Opening BINARY mode data connection.
226: Transfer complete.
Cmd: MDTM 20171205112659 SuperAccount/CreateAdminUser.cshtml
SuperAccount/CreateAdminUser.cshtml:
...count/CreateAdminUser.cshtml:   ETA:   0:00   25.00/ 25.00 B   387.52 kB/s  
...count/CreateAdminUser.cshtml:   ETA:   0:00   25.00/ 25.00 B   339.07 B/s  
SuperAccount/CreateAdminUser.cshtml:                    25.00 B   339.07 B/s  
SuperAccount/CreateAdminUser.cshtml:                    25.00 B   339.07 B/s  
213: 20171205112659
Cmd: SIZE SuperAccount/Index.cshtml
213: 198
Cmd: MDTM SuperAccount/Index.cshtml
213: 20171205111515
Cmd: PASV
425: Cannot open data connection.
Cmd: PORT 10,252,28,100,231,121
Passive mode refused.
501: Server cannot accept argument.
We verified the azure publish profile and see that passive mode is set true.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. We've been using this method of deployment for months without issue but all of a sudden this is causing a problem, but only on one of our web apps so far.

Comment: Same problem here, it started on Dec 27 for me...

Comment: anyone have any solutions for this?

Comment: I think it depends on the server load where webapp is hosted by azure. Couple of things we did, not sure which one worked. 1) Scaled our webapp from B1 Basic to S1 Standard plan. 2) Removed copy of files in pipelines which were not needed on every change. 3) Set options:  max-time: 15 in pipeline (this can be tuned on your need).